# unable to hide the ul if it has no li inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide the ul, on page and also using ajax because some parts of the website are ajax based.

```
<ul class="sub-nav-20-m" id="filtersList_m">

</ul>
```

so here is the code i am trying but it is not doing anything

```
window.onload = function(){
 alert("hi");
    $(".sub-nav-20-m").each(function(){  
    if($(this).children().length == 0){ 
        $(this).hide(); 
        
        } else{
        $(this).show();
        
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS for this:

```css
.sub-nav-20-m:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with ajax. It is using jquery and it is correct by itself. Do you get any errors? Is it executed at all? Do you get the alert message shown?

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to first check for empty LI tags for whatever reason and remove them, then if the element is empty, hide it. As a separate function, you could call it after window.onload or after an ajax transaction.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    hideEmptyULs()
  }, 2000)
}

function hideEmptyULs() {
  $('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function() {
      if ($(this).children().length === 0) $(this).remove()
    })
    if ($(this).children().length === 0) $(this).hide()
  });
}
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='thing'></ul>
<ul class='thing2'>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```